# nodejs, how to do debugging using GDB

Tags: node.js, gdb

After searching in google, I found the below way to do gdb on nodejs application,
build node with ./configure --debug option and then do

```
  gdb --args ~/node_g start.js
```

Using this I am trying to debug a small program, but after setting the breakpoint, I am not able to see that it is breaking in that function,

My simple program gdb_node.js looks like this:

```
 function abc() {
    console.log("In abc");
 }

 function bcd() {
    abc();
    console.log("Done abc");
 }

 bcd();
```

Now I am issuing gdb:

```
(gdb) b bcd
 Function "bcd" not defined.
 Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
 Breakpoint 1 (bcd) pending.
 (gdb) run
 Starting program: /Users/mayukh/node_g gdb_node.js
 Reading symbols for shared libraries
```

++++......................................................................................................................................... done

```
 In abc
 Done abc

 Program exited normally.
 (gdb)
```

Can someone please let me know what I am missing here?

Regards,
-M-

Answer (score 15):

`gdb` tries to lookup `bcd` symbol in debugging information generated from c++ source. It seems that you actually want to debug javascript and not c++.

V8 has built in debugger, and node.js has [client](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_debugger.js) for debugger [protocol](https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/DebuggerProtocol)

To start node.js with debugger client attached to program:

```
node inspect test.js
```

You can set breakpoints using debugger [commands](http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_breakpoints):

```
sh-3.2$ node inspect test.js
< debugger listening on port 5858
connecting... ok
break in test.js:10
  8 }
  9
 10 bcd();
 11
 12 });
debug> sb(6)
  5 function bcd() {
* 6   abc();
  7   console.log("Done abc");
  8 }
  9
 10 bcd();
 11
 12 });
debug>
```

Or use `debugger` keyword:

```
 function abc() {
    console.log("In abc");
 }

 function bcd() {
    debugger;
    abc();
    console.log("Done abc");
 }

 bcd();
```

=

```
sh-3.2$ node inspect test.js
< debugger listening on port 5858
connecting... ok
break in test.js:11
  9 }
 10
 11 bcd();
 12
 13 });
debug> c
break in test.js:6
  4
  5 function bcd() {
  6   debugger;
  7   abc();
  8   console.log("Done abc");
debug>
```

There are GUI clients for V8 debugger as well: [node-webkit-agent](https://github.com/c4milo/node-webkit-agent), [node-inspector](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector), [eclipse](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Using-Eclipse-as-Node-Applications-Debugger) and others

Comment: Node v8 recommends using `node inspect` instead of `node debug`

Answer (score 1):

Give [Trepan-ni](https://www.npmjs.com/package/trepan-ni) a try. It is a GDB-like debugger based on Node Inspector. I've been using it for over a year, and it works well. I can confirm it works with NodeJS v8 to v14.